# Selected state of Radio Button In Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

---

*Attempt to clarify:* In my Visualforce page I have 3 radio buttons and 2 text fields. If I select the first radio button automatically field 1 is shown and field 2 is hidden.

I select radio button 1 & field 1 and save into the database. When I edit the previously saved data, radio button 1 is not selected. How can I make it selected in edit mode?

---

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Shipping Information">
 <apex:selectRadio value="{!Quote__c.shipping_type__c}" onChange="show(this.value);">
 <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Use Store Settings" itemValue="0"  />
 <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Per Item" itemValue="1" />
 <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Fixed Price Per Order" itemValue="2"/>
 </apex:selectRadio>

     <apex:inputField value="{!Quote__c.storeprice__c}" id="defaultcost" style="display:block;"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Quote__c.price__c}" id="differcost" style="display:none;"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>


 <script>
  function show(t)
  {
   if ( t == 0 ){
    $('[id$="defaultcost"]').show();
    $('[id$="differcost"]').hide();
   }
   else{
    $('[id$="defaultcost"]').hide();
   $('[id$="differcost"]').show();

   }     
 }
```

Comment: what are you doing in onChange?

Comment: @PramodKumar Based upon radio buttons i am showing/hideing the fields.

Comment: Sathya -- would you be so kind as to reword your problem statement using more declarative language and perhaps numbered or bulleted points?  The problem statement is not clear.

Comment: Sathya -- your use of jQuery doesn't follow SFDC VF jQuery conventions - see http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/using-jquery-in-a-visualforce-page and specifically the `$j = jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: @crop1645 where i want to do changes can you suggest me.

Comment: @crop1645 .when i use  $j = jQuery.noConflict(); means i functionality of hide and show is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple construction that mirrors what you are trying to do

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Foo__c" >
<apex:selectRadio value="{!Foo__c.RadioOptionVal__c}">
  <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Value 1" itemValue="1"/>
  <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Value 2" itemValue="2"/>
  <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Value 3" itemValue="3"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
</apex:page>
```

where Foo__c.radioOptionVal__c is a picklist with values '1', '2', '3'

1. If I invoke the page using /apex/foo?id=*someFooId* ..
2. VF will fetch the current value of radioOptionVal__c from the database ...
3. If that value is a string of either '1', '2', or '3', then the proper radio button is defaulted. If the value in the database is null or something other than '1', '2', or '3', then no radio button is defaulted